# Inserting into active session in php

Tags: php

How do i insert into the current session row"
The table name is lodges and the session name is lodge.

```
    <?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['lodge'])) {
    header("Location:lodge.php");
}
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pwd","db");

$company_shortbio= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['company_shortbio']); 
$company_longbio = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['company_longbio']);
$company_location = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['company_location']);
$service1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['service1']);
$service2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['service2']);
$service3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['service3']);
$service4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['service4']);

$sql="UPDATE lodges SET 
company_shortbio='$company_shortbio',company_longbio='$company_longbio',company_location='$company_location',service1='$service1',service2='$service2',service3='$service3',service4='$service4'

"; 

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {

      header("Location:lodgeprofile.php?error");
  }




else{

 header("Location:lodgeprofile.php?success");
    exit;
}
?>
```

the data is inserting into the tabe,but its inserting on all the rows and not the specific active session.Please help,im new to php.And i also know that this code is vulnerable to injections.This is just a small assignment.The table primary key is lodge_id

Comment: You have no WHERE clause or LIMIT so it will update all rows

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not Using a condition or a limit the query will update every row in the table.

```
UPDATE table SET (column=value) WHERE condition(s) LIMIT n
```

Example with Condition:

```
$sql = "UPDATE lodges SET company_shortbio='$company_shortbio',company_longbio='$company_longbio',company_location='$company_location',service1='$service1',service2='$service2',service3='$service3',service4='$service4' WHERE somecolumn=$somevalue";
```

Example with LIMIT:

```
$sql = "UPDATE lodges SET company_shortbio='$company_shortbio',company_longbio='$company_longbio',company_location='$company_location',service1='$service1',service2='$service2',service3='$service3',service4='$service4' LIMIT 1";
```

You make also combine WHERE and LIMIT within your queries.

Comment: could you edit the code so that i get a clear picture,im new to php.

Comment: $sql="UPDATE lodges SET (lodge_id=cname) WHERE $_SESSION['lodge'] = $row['lodge_id'] LIMIT 1
company_shortbio='$company_shortbio',company_longbio='$company_longbio',company_location='$company_location',service1='$service1',service2='$service2',service3='$service3',service4='$service4' im getting an error here

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: thanks chris.its now inserting in one row,but not the specific active session.adding WHERE $_SESSION['lodge'] = $row['lodge_id']; is giving me an error,unexpected T_.im not sure how to combine the limit with the session check

Comment: That's because you need WHERE lodge_id=$_SESSION['lodge'] but it appears in your code at least that you do not have a column that matches lodge_id in your table. its only modifying 1 row as you limited to 1 row.

Comment: thank you all.this helped me solve it.now i can work on sorting out the security of my code from sql injections

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that in another piece of code there is someone setting $_SESSION['lodge'] to the lodge_id of the current user.

In this case you will have to do something like:

```
$lodge_id=$_SESSION['lodge'];
$sql="UPDATE ... WHERE lodge_id=$lodge_id;";
```

However you are right, this code is prone to injections. The best way I know to avoid injections is by using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

One more thing: after redirecting if the $_SESSION has no 'lodge', you should exit, else the subsequent code will be executed anyway.